# Conditional PowerShell parameters

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, conditional-statements

Is there a way to have some of the parameters mandatory based on some condition (for example, if one of the parameters is absent or false) in a PowerShell function?

My idea is to be able to call a function in two ways. A concrete example is a function that gets a list from SharePoint - I should be able to call it with relative URL of the list (one and only parameter) OR with a web URL and a list display name (two parameters, both mandatory, but only if list relative URL is not used).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Christian indicated, this can be accomplished via ParameterSetNames. Take a look at this example:

```
function Get-MySPWeb {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="set1")]
    param (
        [parameter(ParameterSetName="set1")] $RelativeUrl,
        [parameter(ParameterSetName="set2")] $WebUrl,
        [parameter(ParameterSetName="set2", Mandatory=$true)] $DisplayName
    )
    Write-Host ("Parameter set in action: " + $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
    Write-Host ("RelativeUrl: " + $RelativeUrl)
    Write-Host ("WebUrl: " + $WebUrl)
    Write-Host ("DisplayName: " + $DisplayName)
}
```

If you run it with `-RelativeUrl Foo` it will bind to "set1". If you call this function without any parameters it will also bind to "set1".

(**Note -** *when no parameters are provided in PowerShell v3 (with Windows 8 consumer preview) it will bind to "set1", however it will error binding in PowerShell v2 unless you add `[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="set1")]` to the parameter block. Thanks @x0n for the DefaultParameterSetName tip!*)

If you try to run it with a parameter value from both sets you will get an error.

If you run it with `-WebUrl Bar` it will prompt you for a parameter value for DisplayName, because it's a mandatory parameter.

Comment: This is exactly I needed! Thank you! Only one thing: when I run this with no params, I get an error (but I wanted it this way).
One follow-up question: when using parametersets it is intended to use switch with the $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName variable, right?

Comment: Right, `$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName` is there so you can take the appropriate action based on the parameter set evaluated by the parameter binding process. BTW it's interesting you got an error, it seems this is a difference in behavior between PSv2 and PSv3.

Comment: The trick to making it work like v3 is to use a default parameter set directive. I've edited your answer to show this.

Comment: If you're building your Cmdlet as a .NET assembly then DefaultParameterSetName must go in the [Cmdlet()] attribute - it won't work if you add a seperate [CmdletBinding()] attribute

Answer (score 2):

There is a much more powerful option, called dynamic parameters, which allows to dynamically add parameters depending on the value of other parameters or any other condition.

You must structure your script in a different way, declaring the regular parameters as usual, and including a `DynamicParam` block to create dynamic parameters, a `Begin` block to initialize variables using the dynamic parameters , and a `Process` block with the code run by the script, which can use regular parameters, and variables initialized in `Begin`. It looks like this:

```
param( 
  # Regular parameters here
)

DynamicParam {
  # Create a parameter dictionary
  $runtimeParams = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

  # Populate it with parameters, with optional attributes
  # For example a parameter with mandatory and pattern validation
  $attribs = New-Object  System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

  $mandatoryAttrib = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
  $mandatoryAttrib.Mandatory = $true
  $attribs.Add($mandatory)

  $patternAttrib = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidatePatternAttribute('your pattern here')
  $attribs.Add($patternAttrib)

  # Create the parameter itself with desired name and type and attribs
  $param = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('ParameterName', String, $attribs)

  # Add it to the dictionary
  $runtimeParams.Add('ParameterName', $param)

  # Return the dictionary
  $ruintimeParams
}

Begin {
  # If desired, move dynamic parameter values to variables
  $ParameterName = $PSBoundParameters['ParameterName']
}

Process {
  # Implement the script itself, which can use both regular an dynamic parameters
}
```

Of course, the interesting part is that you can add conditions on the `DynamicParam` section and the `Begin` section to create different parameters depending on anything, for example other parameter values. The dynamic parameters can have any name, type (string, int, bool, object...) an attributes (mandatory, position, validate set...), and they are created before the execution of the script so that you get parameter tab completion (IntelliSense) in any environment which supports it, like the PowerShell console, the [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx) or the Visual Studio Code editor.

A typical example would be to create a different set of dynamic parameters depending on the value of a regular parameter, by using a simple `if` in the `DynamicParam` section.

Google "PowerShell dynamic parameters" for extra information, like showing help for dynamic parameters. For example:

- [PowerShell Magazine Dynamic Parameters in PowerShell](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/05/29/dynamic-parameters-in-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Even though the original answer was really what I needed, this is definitely very interesting way of solving the problem and I can see its power in some complicated cases. Also, I would say this option is much neglected and therefore not very well known. Thanks again for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [parameters set naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/parameter-attribute-declaration).

You can assign an exclusive parameter to a different parameter set name.

Comment: Can you give me a little example how can I accomplish what I wrote?

Comment: Read here http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands.aspx I'm too busy now to write an example but link give a really good explanation.

Comment: Code in comments looks bad... but:

param (
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'rel', Mandatory = $true)][string]$RelativeUrl,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'web', Mandatory = $true)][string]$WebUrl,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'web', Mandatory = $true)][string]$DisplayName
)

Now you have to parameter *sets*, one for each scenario. Parameter can go to multiple sets or all sets (if no parameterSetName is specified). More in help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a non-specific page, `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/windows-powershell`.