# Requiring parameters in PowerShell when another parameter is present

Tags: powershell

Everything I have read so far tells me that this should work. This is intended to be a script for automating the transfer out of AD accounts. How I would like it to work is if the -TransferHomeDrive switch is set, then it will require names for the old server and new server.

I believe I should be able to do this with a parameter set, however if I just have the single parameter set, plus the default parameters, it will always prompt me for an old and new server. Here is my `param` statement:

```powershell
Param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$Username,

    [switch]$RetainGroups,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$False)]
    [switch]$TransferHomeDrive,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$OldServer,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$NewServer
)
```

So, if it were working, you could run

```
Move-AccountOut -Username JohnSmith -RetainGroups
```

And it won't schedule a home drive transfer. However, if you were to run

```
Move-AccountOut -Username JohnSmith -RetainGroups -TransferHomeDrive
```

It would prompt for `OldServer` and `NewServer`.

I've found similar questions, including these, but it's still not working:

[PowerShell mandatory parameter depend on other parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533763/powershell-mandatory-parameter-depend-on-other-parameter)

[Having a optional parameter that requires another parameter to be present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131389/having-a-optional-parameter-that-requires-another-paramter-to-be-present)

I believe that it would work if I created a second parameter set, that included ALL parameters, including `Username` and `RetainGroups`, but it seems like according to the other posts that I should be able to have it work the way that I have it written, where `Username` and `RetainGroups` are "global" parameters, and `OldServer` and `NewServer` are only required when `TransferHomeDrive` is set

Comment: How is this not working currently? Does it not prompt? Does it always prompt? Does it error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have only one parameter set `TransferHomeDrive`, you does not have other *default* parameter set. You should let PowerShell know, that another named parameter set exists, by explicitly declare it in `CmdletBinding` or `Parameter` attribute.

```powershell
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferHomeDrive')]
Param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$Username,

    [switch]$RetainGroups,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$False)]
    [switch]$TransferHomeDrive,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$OldServer,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$NewServer
)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! That worked great, now that I look at the threads that I linked to, that was clearly the problem, I think I was just getting tunnel vision after trying to figure it out for so long. Cheers!!

Comment: If that answer worked, please mark it as accepted by checking the checkmark to the left of it (just below the Up Vote/Down Vote)