# Is it possible to combine a parameter list across functions?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script with 2 functions that are very similar in parameters.
Is it possible to combine the parameters (Computername, Port, OtherVariable) into some sort of set?

In this example, it's only 3 parameters but in reality it's 11 parameters.
I'm thinking of doing this because the parameterlist is starting to become a bit long.

```
function Function1 
{
  Param(
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Filename,
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Computername,
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Port,
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$OtherVariable
    )
  Process
  {

  }
}

function Function2
{
  Param(
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Url,
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Computername,
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Port,
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$OtherVariable
    )
  Process
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: It's called `parameter sets`: [Conditional powershell parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10748978)

Comment: I've tried looking a bit into `parameter sets` but I don't think it can work across functions. Do you have an example? Or are you trying to say that I should combine the functions and make use of `parameter sets`?

Comment: The latter, of course. You can make a superfunction that calls one of the existing ones depending on the parameters.

Comment: While I would like to have an option to use `parameter sets` across functions (mostly because one is named `Export-MyObjects` and the other function is named `Compile-MyObjects`), I believe that your suggestion is the best answer I'm going to get.

Could you leave an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Not declare your parameters. But you then lose any auto-help and this would make it difficult to maintain (unless you added comments, detailing the expected/accepted params - but this would still require maintenance).
2. Move the code common to both functions into a 3rd function (not sure if this is possible in your use-case?)
3. Create a super*-function, as woxxom mentioned in the comment to your post, with all the params plus Compile and Export [switch] params. Then either move the compile and export code into separate functions, or include in the super-function.

*super being superset