# Can I make one parameter mandatory based on the _value_ of a different parameter?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

If param One is set to bbb then I want to make param Two mandatory. Is it possible to do this with parameter sets somehow or will I just have to add this logic to the script itself?

Example idea of what I need:

```
 param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'default')]
        [ValidateSet(“aaa”, ”bbb”, ”ccc”, "ddd")]
        [String]
        $One,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'default')]
        [ValidateScript( { $One -eq 'bbb'; THEN MAKE THIS PARAM MANDATORY! })]
        [String]
        $Two
    )
```

The value of $One seems to not be set yet as I tried doing this and one.txt is empty

```
[ValidateScript( { $One > One.txt; $true })]
```

### Edit

While there is DynamicParam{} that looks like its only if you have begin,process,end, etc setup. This is a simple function that I don't want to add that to it. Also DynamicParam seems to require a bizarre amount of boilerplate code to work

### Edit

It looks like DynamicParam is the only way, but I think it crazy. It's weird and not readable, but I'd still prefer Powershell to handle validation for me.

Doing it myself though is still pretty simple:

```
if ($One -eq 'bbb' -and -not $Two) {
    ThrowError Param Two required when One set to $One
}
```

Comment: looks like DynamicParam requires PROCESS though which i dont want to use

Comment: Without Process block it will work. See the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use the *default value* for parameter `-Two` to enforce the desired logic**, via an `if` statement that uses `Throw`:

```
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'default')]
  [ValidateSet('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd')]
  [String]
  $One,

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'default')]
  [String]
  $Two = $(if ($One -eq 'bbb') { Throw "-Two must be passed if -One equals 'bbb'." })
)

"-One: $One; -Two: $Two"
```

Note: *Emulating* a (conditionally) mandatory parameter with `Throw` means that the behavior differs from a regular `Mandatory` parameter in that the latter *prompts* when a value isn't given.

A solution based on validation attributes would be preferable, but **validation attributes aren't designed for *cross*-parameter validation**, and no particular order of their evaluation is guaranteed.

The above solution relies on the fact that default values are evaluated *after* explicitly passed arguments have been bound.

The **much more verbose alternative is to use a  [*dynamic* parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#dynamic-parameters)**, as shown in [Wasif Hasan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477921/45375), relies on the same timing, though it does have the advantage of exhibiting normal prompt-for-a-missing-mandatory-value behavior.

As of this writing, Wasif's answer doesn't work as posted, so here's a working solution; note how **the use of `DynamicParam` syntactically requires (at least one of) the `begin`, `process` and `end` blocks**.

```
# Syntax requires PSv5+:
using namespace System.Management.Automation

param( 
  [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='default')]
  [ValidateSet('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd')]
  [String]$One
)

# Define parameter -Two *dynamically*, so that its Mandatory property
# can be based on the specific value of the already-bound static -One parameter.
DynamicParam {

  # Create a the dictionary of dynamic parameters.
  $dict = [RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()

  # Define and add the -Two parameter 
  $paramName = 'Two'
  $dict.Add(
    $paramName,
    [RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new(
      $paramName,
      [string],
      [ParameterAttribute] @{
        ParameterSetName = 'default'
        # *Conditionally* make the parameter mandatory, depending on the value
        # of the already-bound static -One parameter.
        Mandatory = $One -eq 'bbb'
      }
    )
  )

  # Return the dictionary
  return $dict
}

begin {

  # NOTE: Dynamic parameter values do not become local variables the way
  #       they do for static parameters; the value must be accessed via the
  #       automatic $PSBoundParameters dictionary.
  $Two = $PSBoundParameters['Two']

  "-One: $One; -Two: $Two"

}
```

Comment: perfect. maybe not as declarative as like actual validator syntax but I like having it live with the param itself instead of script body

Comment: +1, excellent effort. Thank you! I need to enrich myself more with knowledge on deep powershell. Darn I wish I could write answers like you and our fellow enthusiasts. I didn't use ParameterSet because I thought it binds one parameter with another based on the existence of other. So I didn't used it in my answer. But you have shown how to do it. Thanks again for correcting my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the nice feedback, @WasifHasan, but please consider fixing your answer, because, irrespective of the somewhat incidental parameter-set issue, the code simply doesn't work, and it won't be obvious to future readers how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for dynamic parameters: [Conditional PowerShell parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748978/conditional-powershell-parameters)

```
param( 
  [String]$One
)

DynamicParam {
  # Create a parameter dictionary
  $runtimeParams = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

  # Populate it with parameters, with optional attributes

  $attribs = New-Object  System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

  $mandatoryAttrib = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
  $mandatoryAttrib.Mandatory = ($one -eq "bbb")
  $attribs.Add($mandatoryAttrib)

  $param = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('Two', String, $attribs)
}
Begin {
  # If desired, move dynamic parameter values to variables
  $ParameterName = $PSBoundParameters['Two']
}

  # Do like regular
```

Without process block it will work.

Comment: im getting error Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement. should be `$param = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('Two', [string], $attribs`

Comment: this also does not seem to work. not specifying param Two if One=bbb does not raise any errors

Comment: While use of a dynamic parameter is a possible - if quite verbose - solution, please make sure that your code actually works before posting it: not only is it broken outright (fails on invocation), it is missing crucial parts.